# Вызов ''.join ведёт к ошибке: TypeError: can only join an iterable

Tags: python, list, join

Почему код:

```
vesh = [dct[bots[l]][s]['m'],dct[bots[l]][s]['p']]
name = ''.join(vesh[0])
price = ''.join(vesh[1])
weapon = name + price
```

приводит к ошибке:

```
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске, приведите конкретные данные, которые хранятся в vesh.

Comment: `join(iterable)` ожидает в качестве аргумента объект который поддерживает итерирование - ошибка собственно именно об этом и говорит

Comment: @MaxU может, ответ опубликуете?

Comment: Может попробовать `(`dct[bots[l]][s]['m'],dct[bots[l]][s]['p']`)` ? За место квадратных `[]`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я опубликовал ответ с примерами итерируемых объектов

Answer (score 4):

[str.join(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) ожидает в качестве аргумента `iterable` - объект поддерживающий [итерирование](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-iterable).

> **iterable** An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as `list`, `str`,
>   and `tuple`) and some non-sequence types like `dict`, `file` objects, and
>   objects of any classes you define with an [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) or [`__getitem__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)
>   method. Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places
>   where a sequence is needed (`zip()`, `map()`, ...). When an iterable
>   object is passed as an argument to the built-in function [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#iter), it
>   returns an iterator for the object. This iterator is good for one pass
>   over the set of values. When using iterables, it is usually not
>   necessary to call `iter()` or deal with iterator objects yourself. The
>   for statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary
>   unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop.
>   See also [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-iterator), [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-sequence), and [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-generator).

по простому на русском [(c) @jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620199/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-join-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b5-typeerror-can-only-join-an-iterable/620454?noredirect=1#comment861976_620454):

> `''.join()` принимает составной объект—коллекцию строк, такую как
>   список, которую можно в for-цикл передать, чтобы все строки обойти

Вот один из способов определения является ли объект итерируемым и заодно примеры итерируемых объектов:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: isinstance(['a','b'], collections.Iterable)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: isinstance('ab', collections.Iterable)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: isinstance('a', collections.Iterable)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: isinstance([1,2], collections.Iterable)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: isinstance(1, collections.Iterable)
Out[6]: False  # NOT iterable

In [7]: isinstance((1), collections.Iterable)
Out[7]: False  # NOT iterable

In [8]: isinstance((1,), collections.Iterable)
Out[8]: True

In [9]: isinstance({'a':'b'}, collections.Iterable)
Out[9]: True

In [10]: isinstance({}, collections.Iterable)
Out[10]: True

In [11]: isinstance(set([1]), collections.Iterable)
Out[11]: True

In [12]: isinstance(set(), collections.Iterable)
Out[12]: True

In [13]: isinstance(open('d:/temp/aaa.txt', 'w'), collections.Iterable)
Out[13]: True
```

Comment: для простоты можно сказать что `''.join` принимает составной объект—коллекцию строк, такую как список, которую можно в for-цикл передать, чтобы все строки обойти.

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, лучше и не скажешь - добавил в ответ в виде цитаты